# create a pandas dataframe from python list containing tuple with nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have wrestled with this for a few days now, but can't figure it out.
I'm trying to create a dataframe "account_activity" from the results of an api get.
i make an api call and print it out.

```
account_activities = api.get_activities()
print(account_activities)
```

returns:

```
[AccountActivity({   'activity_type': 'FILL',
    'cum_qty': '100',
    'id': '20211111105648607::a0ef3f04-ff00-4b8e-834d-54737d89c332',
    'leaves_qty': '0',
    'order_id': '32c9a40e-e6d2-4c7c-8949-a39ad32b535f',
    'order_status': 'filled',
    'price': '187.09',
    'qty': '56',
    'side': 'sell',
    'symbol': 'U',
    'transaction_time': '2021-11-11T15:56:48.607222Z',
    'type': 'fill'})]
```

How do I create a dataframe "account_activity" where the keys are the column headers and the index is the transaction_time is the row index with values in the rows?

Comment: I had to go in a different direction but I figured it out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `j` is te JSON from your `AccountActivity` object:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(j, index=['']).set_index('transaction_time',drop=True)
```

How you get the JSON depends on the APIs you're using. Perhaps

```
j = account_activities[0].__dict__
```

will work?

Comment: hmmm... it throws an error
KeyError: "None of ['transaction_time'] are in the col

Comment: I guess `j` is different for you. What is it for you?